# Bulk inert to parent children tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following three tables (each RobotPart has exactly one arm and one leg). I have a large number of {arm, leg} pairs need to be inserted. Any new combinations of arm and leg will create a new entry in RobotPart. Any existing combination will not be inserted. No updates are needed for either parent or children. I need preserve the identity columns. Any efficient ways to accomplish this in SQL?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Arm](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Arm] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Leg](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Leg] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RobotPart](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ArmId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LegId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.RobotPart] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RobotPart]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.RobotPart_dbo.Arm_ArmId] FOREIGN KEY([ArmId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Arm] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RobotPart] WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.RobotPart_dbo.Leg_LegId] FOREIGN KEY([LegId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Leg] ([Id])
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Insert new arms and legs using a LEFT OUTER JOINs from your source table to the arms and legs table, respectively. (a separate insert statement for each table)
Step 2: Insert the new combinations using an inner join from your source table to arms and legs and a left outer join from the your source table to the RobotPart table.

Comment: +1, I have a implementation similar to your suggestion, not sure if any improvements can be made.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my initial try on it using MERGE. Not sure how this compare to Lmu92 proposed.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[RobotPart_udtt] AS TABLE(
    [Arm] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Leg] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[prc_Component_Create]
    @robotParts [RobotPart_udtt] READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @messageId INT
    DECLARE @status INT

    MERGE [Arm] AS TARGET
    USING (
            SELECT 
                tR.arm AS Model
            FROM @robotParts AS tR
    ) AS SOURCE
    ON TARGET.Model = SOURCE.Model
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT 
        (
            Model
        ) 
        VALUES 
        (
            SOURCE.Model
        );

    MERGE [Leg] AS TARGET
    USING (
            SELECT 
                tR.leg AS Model
            FROM @robotParts AS tR
    ) AS SOURCE
    ON TARGET.Model = SOURCE.Model
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT 
        (
            Model
        ) 
        VALUES 
        (
            SOURCE.Model
        );

    WITH NewParts (ArmId, LegId, Name)
    AS 
    (
        SELECT tA.Id
            , tL.Id
            , tR.Name
        FROM @robotParts AS tR
            INNER JOIN [Arm] AS tA
                ON tR.Arm = tA.Model
            INNER JOIN [Leg] AS tL
                ON tR.Leg = tL.Model
    )
    INSERT INTO RobotPart (Name, ArmId, LegId) 
    SELECT tN.Name
        , tN.ArmId
        , tN.LegId
    FROM NewParts AS tN
        LEFT JOIN RobotPart AS tR
            ON tR.ArmId = tN.ArmId
            AND tR.LegId = tN.LegId
        WHERE tR.ArmId IS NULL AND tR.LegId IS NULL
END
```